# Android Studio Error after error (Failed to notify build listener)

Tags: android-studio

Problem: I am using Android Studio 2.3.3, when I open my project that was done in school (same ver)

I am getting this msg 'Error:Failed to notify build listener.'

Gradle settings: Use defualt gradle wrapper and Offline Work checked on.

I don't think I ever had so many problems trying to get program to work.

Googling 1 problem and then fixing it leads to another.

I am getting desperate here because some of solutions from google require me to download stuff, and this takes forver since my internet is super slow, some of those files didn't even help.

Could someone lead me in the right direction and point files that are worth downloading?

After installing some file that android studio recommended, I am getting this:
"Error:Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;"

Comment: Why are you using such an old Android Studio? The current Android Studio version is 3.5.3, and you are using 2.3.3. Try to upgrade the Android Studio, maybe it'll fix your problems or maybe it'll give you more meaningful error information. Maybe some files which you have downloaded aren't compatible with the old Android Studio. Try to install the latest Android Studio and then try to find out the solution, if the problem still exists.

Comment: I have to use this version since its the one we use in class.
Gotta make sure it works both on my pc and school pc, this is why I am using 2.3.3

Comment: @VladimirDinic
If I use upgraded Android Studio at home, will project still work in school where the version is 2.3.3 ?

Comment: I see that this project already works on your school's PC. There could be some incompatibilities in different Android versions, so I suggest to try to run in that Android Studio version.

You have several options which you can try for the beginning:
- Invalidate cashes/restart
- Check/update gradle version
- Install all things which Android Studio requires